# How can i change the color of dropdownlist arrow?

Tags: asp.net

How can i change hover color of dropdownlist arrow button ? here when hover on dropdown its in blue color . i want change this to yellow . how can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate solution: use Ajax DropDownExtender you can easily change css style.

```
<ajaxToolkit:DropDownExtender runat="server" ID="DDE"
TargetControlID="TextLabel" 
DropDownControlID="DropPanel" />
```

visit this link for demo:[DropDown Demonstration](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/DropDown/DropDown.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

this will be done on page load

```
foreach(ListItem item in ddlName.Items) {
    if(item.Value == "someStringValue") {
        item.Attributes.Add("style", "color:red")
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work, you can move this code to the DataBound event of the Drop Down List.

Comment: there is an ^ arrow in  dropdownbox . if i click or hover on that its changing to blue color . how can i change this blue to some other color?